# Before and After pseudo background overlaying text

Tags: css, safari

So i've made some little tabs:

https://jsfiddle.net/pkpy08wy/2/

They display fine on chrome, and even fine on safari on iPad and iPhone. But on safari on a mac the background overlays the text.

Any ideas?

```
.address_tab {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px 8px;
    color: #14528b;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.address_tab::before {
    content: ''; /* To generate the box */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: -999;
    background: #d0d0d0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #d0d0d0, #e8e8e8);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #d0d0d0, #e8e8e8);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #d0d0d0, #e8e8e8);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #d0d0d0 , #e8e8e8);
    transform: perspective(4px) rotateX(1deg);
    border: 1px #b2b2b2 solid;
}

.address_tab::before {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

<div class="address_tab">
  Delivery Details
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i did stumble across this post http://katydecorah.com/code/z-index-and-transform/ which seems to have the solution for your problem. It's a good read by they way :)

Here's an updated fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/a8zv69ka/

```
.address_tab {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 10px 30px 8px;
   color: #14528b;
   margin-left: 20px;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.address_tab::before {
   content: ''; /* To generate the box */
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
   background: #d0d0d0;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #d0d0d0, #e8e8e8);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #d0d0d0, #e8e8e8);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #d0d0d0, #e8e8e8);
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #d0d0d0 , #e8e8e8);
   transform: perspective(4px) rotateX(1deg) translateZ(-1px);
   border: 1px #b2b2b2 solid;
}

.address_tab::before {
   -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
   border-top-left-radius: 10px;
   border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 }

<div class="address_tab">
  Delivery Details
</div>
```

Comment: This worked! just have to change my padding :) thank you! definitely will give that a read too.

Comment: @SamJones glad i could help! :)

Comment: @SamJones: IE11 doesn't support `preserve3d` so this solution will fail there

Comment: mine or this doesnt work in firefox either, think i need to simplify my tab, i'll try post an answer when i get it working in everything, but @localZero answered my safari question. The tabs aren't even important to me, its the designer pushing them.

Comment: Seems to work with FF but i can confirm that it doesn't work IE 11, thanks for pointing that out @LGSon